# What is vanilla tor?

Tags: anonymity

I'm new to privacy and anonymity. I'm reading a paper about efficient path prediction for Tor circuit and then I came across the term name *vanilla tor*. Can anyone give me a precise/clear definition of this? please. Thank you in advance. I found this,

> This test examines the reachability of the Tor network

So, is this just a reachability test? or there's more to it?

Comment: Vanilla Tor means using only the official Tor client and nothing else.

Comment: ...in contrast to the *Tor Browser* (or former known as *Tor Browser Bundle* resp. *TBB*).

Answer (score 1):

Tor can have different meanings. Some understand Tor as

- the company
- the community
- the network
- the protocol
- the software (which can be Tor Browser or only Tor)

To clarify someone invented vanilla Tor for Tor the software. The thing you can download and build from https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/. It is also sometimes called *little-t-tor*.